# Invalid path expression near attempt to access element

Tags: arrays, json, jq, json-path-expression

When trying to change a single element in an array, I get `Invalid path expression near attempt to access element` - but only when the array is captured from `--rawInput`.

Example:

```
# input: [ 1, 0 ]
. as $list | $list[0] = 30
# output: [ 30, 0 ]
```

But this doesn't work:

```
# input: 1,0
split(",") | map(tonumber) as $list | $list[0] = 30
# Invalid path expression near attempt to access element 0 of [1,0]
```

- [Working example](https://jqterm.com/bbee16b98d741cc079a137c69dbd2c20?query=.%20as%20%24list%20%7C%20%24list%5B0%5D%20%3D%2030)
- [Not working example](https://jqterm.com/5cac96271e2d235f2554543d852f5973?query=split%28%22%2C%22%29%20%7C%20map%28tonumber%29%20as%20%24list%20%7C%20%24list%5B0%5D%20%3D%2030&raw-input=true)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your attempt failed because of following :

> Note that the LHS of assignment operators refers to a value in `.`. Thus
>   `$var.foo = 1` won’t work as expected (`$var.foo` is not a valid or useful
>   path expression in `.`); use `$var | .foo = 1` instead.

From the [Assignment section of the jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Assignment).

It likely only worked in your first `jq` command because `$list` and `.` were equal.

Following that you could have used the following :

```
split(",") | map(tonumber) as $list | $list | .[0] = 30
```

Or more simply in your case :

```
split(",") | map(tonumber) | .[0]=30
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I hadn't quite realised that at all, but it works perfectly, thank you 